# Sublime Text move cursor to word found with Ctrl+f

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Is there any way to simply do this? Say I search for a word `foo` that has 5 occurrences in the file. I use `Ctrl+f` and hit `Enter` three times to see the third occurrence, and then I decide I want my cursor at that word. What do I do?

I'm aware of incremental find: `ctrl+i` however that doesn't seem to allow me to cycle through all occurrences in the file until I found the one I want.

Comment: Once the occurrence you want is selected, just hit Esc and you will be able to edit it.

Comment: That works, thanks! Wow, can't believe I wasn't able to figure that out

Comment: As for Ctrl+i you can use shortcuts to cycle. F3 & Shift+F3 in Windows & Linux, Cmd+G & Cmd+Shift+G in OS X.